# Self hosted Snappy Store

Tags: ubuntu-core

Just like a self-hosted deb repository, is it possible to self-host a Snappy Store for private snapps? I have found that debs can be converted to snapps and that snapps can be submitted to the Ubuntu Snappy Store but I am unable to gather any details about a privately hosted Store.

Comment: you could probably fork webdm, and rewrite it -https://code.launchpad.net/webdm - otherwise there isn't any private store - but yeah I don't see anything stoping people from writing their own web interface. or just hosting them to download and local install...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Snap is a monopoly, it has been designed to be fully controlled by Canonical, even "Branded Stores" have to be on their servers.
Private snaps also must be registered on their store so you will always be tied to their censorship and downtimes.

There was an alternative (https://github.com/noise/snapstore) but Canonical modified Snap to make it harder to work (ex: you can't create Ubuntu Core images with snap packages that aren't registered on their store, etc..).

I recommend you to avoid snap & ubuntu core and try any other alternative like Flatpak or AppImage.

Answer (score 1):

This question have been asked on the #snappy IRC channel and they answered that, for the time being, there will be only one repository.