# How to install a self-created snap on an Ubuntu Core machine?

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I don't understand how the "Snappy workflow" is supposed to work and I feel like I am missing some very basic link.

---

To simplify:

1. Using `snapcraft` I have created a snap `java-hello-world_0_amd64.snap` (from official [examples](https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapcraft/tree/master/examples/java-hello-world)).
2. I have an `ubuntu/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-core-stable` VagrantBox running.
3. I want to run the created snap on the VagrantBox.

What shall I do?

---

If there is no [self-hosted store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647620/self-hosted-snappy-store) is the only option to submit to the Ubuntu Store and wait for approval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to copy your snap to the Ubuntu Core instance and then install it locally using something similar to:

```
$ scp your-snap.snap ubuntu@webdm.local:  
$ ssh ubuntu@webdm.local  
$ sudo snap install your-snap.snap
```

Comment: Trying to install java-hello-world I got an error `java-hello-world_0_amd64.snap failed to install: open /tmp/read-file949861487/unpack/meta/package.yaml: no such file or directory`. I am clueless now.

Comment: @techraf: How are you building your .snap? Sounds like you're using Snapcraft 2.x to create the .snap but you're trying to install it on Ubuntu Core 15.04. In order to target Ubuntu Core 15.04, you must use Snapcraft 1.x.

Comment: @Kyle Yes, right on the spot. I had problems with 1.x and built with 2.x. I did not realize it is so related. I am troubleshooting it now.

Comment: @Kyle the problem is snapcraft version 1 does not work in all example in https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapcraft.

Comment: @ChrisIan indeed, none of them to be exact. You need to refer to the [Snapcraft 1.x branch](https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapcraft/tree/1.x)